# How does Tinder retain user data when the user logs in from another device?

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to replicate Tinder's mechanism for retaining data on my Android app. It appears that Tinder can restore your profile images and bio:

- After uninstalling and reinstalling the app
- When logging in to a completely new device

(logging in via Facebook)

How do they do this?

I've looked through [Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#db) in the Android Docs and under "Databases" it says to implement SQLite with the Room Persistence Library. However this SQLite database lives in the device of the user so it's not fully persistent - if the user logs in via facebook on another device the data will not be remembered.

The following data is what I'd like to save for my tinder-like app:

- User profile (image) & bio (text)
- Check whether the user has matched before with another user

  - for this, an option I considered was each match stores the other matches profile/facebook ID in their internal storage/sqlite db (local) after they've matched. However if they get a new phone it will be reset
- Google Maps data: how many people swiped in a certain city

What is the recommended way of going about this?

Comment: This can be easily implemented with cloud firestore database and realtime this video should help! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S302SksTMaE&list=PLxabZQCAe5fio9dm1Vd0peIY6HLfo5MCf

Comment: It seems much more expensive than the open source alternatives @Mr.Patel

Comment: Yes ofcourse it is you have two options either use firebase to store data or you can make your own restful api and host it online as per your needs however if you're really targeting say a million users then i won't recommend to use firebase as it's harder to manage as usage grows